# Delete from 'table' where id='selected record '?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I'm selecting records from a table with a Delete button in the echo line. I want to be able to delete the record when I click on the corresponding Delete button. 
This is my delete query to delete the selected record from the other query, but it won't work!

```
$querytwo = 'DELETE FROM paginas WHERE id= $_POST["id"]';
```

I'm doing something wrong. What is it? Here is the full code.

```
    <?php

        include_once("config.php"); //this is the database connection
        $query = "SELECT * FROM paginas "; //selects from the table called paginas
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
            {
            $pagetitle = $row['pagetitle'];
            $toevoeging = $row['toevoeging'];
            $message = $row['message'];

                echo '<article class="topcontent">
       <div class="mct">
        <h2>' . $pagetitle .'</h2>
       </div><br>
       <p class="post-info">'. $toevoeging . '</p>
       <p class="post-text"><br>'.$message.'</p>
      </article>
       <div class="deleteknop">
        <form method="post">';

   echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$row['id'].'">
         <input name="delete" type="submit" value="Delete Now!">
        </form>
       </div>' ;
            }

        $querytwo = 'DELETE FROM paginas WHERE id= $_POST["id"]';

        if (isset($_POST['delete'])) //Deletes the query if 'delete' button is clicked

            {
                $resulttwo = $mysqli->query($querytwo);  
            }

            ?>
```

Got it working. I changed the line to `$querytwo = "DELETE FROM paginas WHERE id= $_POST[id]";` It's functional. Although there was a warning notice saying “`Notice: Undefined index”` but I got rid of it thanks to `error_reporting(0);`

Comment: You have an extract single quote after the `id`.  If the `id` is a number, it doesn't need single quotes.  If it is a string then it should have one before as well.

Comment: Okay, so I changed the line to this because id is an int.
 $querytwo = 'DELETE FROM `paginas` WHERE id= '$row'[id] LIMIT 1';   
Would you say that should do it? Because it's still not deleting anything.

Comment: why do you use one time `mysqli_query($mysqli, $query)` and then `$mysqli->query($querytwo);`

Comment: Because they're two different queries, right? $query is for selecting the records, and $querytwo is for deleting the records

Comment: No.. I mean `mysqli_query `  vs  `$mysqli->query`

Comment: I think I got both lines of code from different code snippets. They both work fine though. I know that because when I specify the id of the record in  the delete query, it deletes it with no problem. It's just when I write any of you guys' delete queries to associate the id with the id in the select query, nothing works. I'm doing something wrong and I just can't spot the problem. It's been driving my crazy for hours..

Comment: if your `$querytwo` is in a second script then is your code wrong. You have to to use `$_POST["id"]`

Comment: Okay,thanks,  but how would you go about writing that code? I've updated the question with your feedback. Can you help me further?

Comment: `<form method="post" action="YourSecondScript.php">` `action=""` is the key

Comment: I don't have a second script for the query. It's all on one page, save for the INSERT INTO query but that's not related to my question. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use double quotes for variable interpolation to work.  With single quotes, the exact string you see is what is getting sent as the database query, which is not a valid query.  Something like this would actually substitute the value of the POST variable in the string:

```
$querytwo = "DELETE FROM paginas WHERE id = $_POST[id]"
```

However, interpolating variables directly into a query string is a bad idea as it can result in a SQL injection vulnerability.  I would advise looking up parameterized queries.

Comment: Thank you, that totally did it. I changed the line to 
$querytwo = "DELETE FROM `paginas` WHERE id= $_POST[id]"; It's functional. Although there was an warning notice saying “Notice: Undefined index” but I got rid of it thanks to error_reporting(0);

Comment: The warning will happen the first time you load the page, before the form is submitted, because $_POST['id'] has not yet been defined.  You can avoid it without suppressing all warnings by moving the variable assignment inside the block where the query is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You could just:

```
$querytwo = 'DELETE FROM `paginas` WHERE id= ' . $row['id'] . ' LIMIT 1';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
$querytwo = 'DELETE FROM paginas WHERE id= $_POST["id"]';
```

no need to use limit, you are using id for reference so it will delete one record.